# How to make different styles using makeStyles in React JS Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I am beginner to React JS and Material UI.

I am trying to make different styles of buttons. For example if the button attribute name= submit,ok,cancel,confirm,alert, those each button's styles should be differ from one another

**App.JS**

```
import CssButton  from './controls/Buttons/Button'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CssButton name="btnSubmit"/> //button style to be changed based on 'name'
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Button.JS**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({

    btnSubmit: {
        background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
    },
    ok:{
        background: 'blue',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
    }
});

function CssButton(props) {
   const classes = useStyles(props);
   return<Button className={classes.btnSubmit}>{props.name}</Button>;
   //return <button className={`classes.${ props.name }`}>   --is it possible pass the props value something like this?
   // {props.name}
   //</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({

    btnSubmit: {
        background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
    },
    ok:{
        background: 'blue',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
    }
});

function CssButton(props) {
   const classes = useStyles(props);
   return(
     <Button className={classes[props.name]}>
       {props.name}
     </Button>
   );
}
```

Comment: but it removes the effect of buttons. when I go to inspect element, its different than when you pass it directly

Comment: change ```useStyles(props)``` to ```useStyles()```

Comment: I changed it, still same

Comment: This should work probably work <Button className={classes[props.name]}> in your case. What style is added to the button then?